Need to set attribute before calling super
I'm creating a custom exception to parse a specific file format. The base class is FileFormatException (I've replaced the name of the file format with FileFormat). It has a constructor public FileFormatException(String filepath) that will output a generic error message, such as "Error parsing <filepath>".
Now, the difficulty occurs when I try and create subclasses for more specific errors. These subclasses would have their own error messages, which requires a method such as public FileFormatException(String message). But this is not possible, as it conflicts with the first constructor (they both have the same parameters).
I tried to solve the issue by having a protected setMessage method in FileFormatException, which the subclasses can call, but this won't work, as Java does not allow setting attributes before calling super().
I have a working solution as well, but it very rigid. When a subclass is invoked, I'm forced to include the default message every time with the subclass's custom message.
The constraints are:

Subclasses must inherit from FileFormatException
The message can only be set by calling super(message), since Exception does not have a setter for the message.

I feel like Java is forcing me into a weird corner, since Exceptions don't have setters.
Example
public class FileFormatException extends Exception {
    public FileFormatException(String filepath) {
        super("Error parsing the file: " + filepath);
    }

    // This is prohibited in Java
    public FileFormatException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}

public class SpecificException extends FileFormatException {
    public SpecificException(String filepath) {
        super("Printing specific error message for: " + filepath);
    }
}

Unsuccessful attempt
public class FileFormatException extends Exception {
    private String message = null;

    public FileFormatException(String filepath) {
        super("Error parsing the file: " + filepath);
    }

    public FileFormatException() {
        if (message == null) { // This is probably not allowed either
            super();
        } else {
            super(message);
        }
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
}

public class SpecificException extends FileFormatException {
    public SpecificException(String filepath) {
        setMessage(message); // Java does not allow this
        super();
    }
}


Just use File or preferably Path for any file system paths, and then there is no ambiguity about whether you mean a message or a file

See JEP 447

Constructor overloading in Java - best practice

If you want a custom message along with file path, why not to create another constructor which will accept both parameters, like public FileFormatException(String filepath, String message) ?

@Alex I tried that, but I found the first parameter to be redundant, as the subclasses' message would already include the filepath. It feels a bit hackish since the method doesn't actually use the first parameter (the first parameter can be anything), it's just there to distinguish it from the other constructor.

@Abra I tried it with Java 22 Preview, but it doesn't allow me to call the setter in the parent class before calling super, probably because this references are prohibited in JEP 447. I'm currently trying to set the message attribute in the FileFormatException, so it can call super(message).

@aiwl having a constructor taking two arguments only appears weird to you, because your exception type lacks the most obvious thing: a method to query the affected path. Once you added this very useful thing (compare to FileSystemException.getFile()), a constructor accepting a message and a path, even if the message contains the path, appears very natural. Having to parse an arbitrary message string to find the path inside, due to the lack of a simple getter, is very annoying.

@Holger I see, that seems useful to have. Nice example.

Just use File or preferably Path for any file system paths, and then there is no ambiguity about whether you mean a message or a file
public FileFormatException(Path path) {
    super("Error parsing the file: " + path);
}
public FileFormatException(String message) {
    super(message);
}
...
public SpecificException(Path path) {
    super(path);
    // or
    super("Something else is wrong with: "+path);
}

